# Making a 2 ramekin recipe into an 8 ramekin recipe: Do I change the cooking time?

Tags: baking, temperature, cooking-time

I've read answers about doubling a casserole recipe in a larger container, or putting two cake pans in the oven instead of one. But what about a recipe that asks you to put your ramekins into a shallow pan with an inch of water in it, and you want to do that with 8 ramekins instead of the two that the recipe is intended for? Do you have to add time? Reduce the temperature? Both?

Comment: Can you post the recipe? Or at least the type of food? It can affect the answer.

Comment: Oven type kinda matters too. Convection seems to deal with scaling much better.

Answer (score 4):

Should be exactly the same - what you are cooking is the same size, how many you are cooking makes no difference. One cupcake or 50 would take the same amount of time to cook, if that's easier to think of. A pan of boiling water in the oven does not care how many ramekins are in it, so long as there's some space between them

Comment: Thanks! I followed your advice, and it went well. Sorry to take so long to answer, but I'm new here, and I am just getting the hang of it.